# Как сделать картинку в Python из двухмерного массива чисел?

Tags: python

```
image = numpy.zeros((ppoints, qpoints))
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image, cmap='flag')
```

Так в Jupyter Notebook картинка выводится на экран

А как в сохранить эту картинку на диске? (просто тапнуть на картинку и нажать "Сохранить" бессмысленно, когда разрешение 20000х20000)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('image.jpg', image)
```

Попробуй так

Comment: matplotlib.image.imsave('name.png', array)
Или так